# Calling super class method in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, super

I have the following code:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    def foo(self, a):
        if a:
            return 'B'
        return super(B, self).foo(a)

class C:
    def foo(self, a):
        return 'C'

class D(B, C):
    def foo(self, a):
        return super().foo(a)

d = D()
print(d.foo(0))
```

When I call `d.foo(0)` based on MRO it first calls the `foo` method of `B` class and inside that, if the condition is wrong and it will return `super(B, self).foo(0)` but class `A` has no foo method and I expect this error:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'foo'
```

but it returns `'C'` from class `C`. Why?

Comment: That's the whole point of `super`.  Think about it - if it were to call the parent directly, you wouldn't need `super` in the language at all, you would just call `A` directly here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`super()` searches the MRO for the *next class* that has the attribute; that `A` doesn't implement it doesn't matter as `C` is still considered.

For `D`, the MRO is `D`, `B`, `A`, `C`:

```
>>> D.__mro__
(<class '__main__.D'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.C'>, <class 'object'>)
```

so `super().foo` in `D` will find `B.foo`, and from `B.foo`, `A` is skipped and `C.foo` is found; you can test this yourself from the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> super(D, d).foo
<bound method B.foo of <__main__.D object at 0x1079edb38>>
>>> super(B, d).foo
<bound method C.foo of <__main__.D object at 0x1079edb38>>
```

This is what a Python implementation of the attribute search algorithm would look like:

```
def find_attribute(type_, obj, name):
    starttype = type(obj)
    mro = iter(starttype.__mro__)

    # skip past the start type in the MRO
    for tp in mro:
        if tp == type_:
            break

    # Search for the attribute on the remainder of the MRO
    for tp in mro:
        attrs = vars(tp)
        if name in attrs:
            res = attrs[name]
            # if it is a descriptor object, bind it
            descr = getattr(type(res), '__get__', None)
            if descr is not None:
                res = descr(
                    res,
                    None if obj is starttype else obj,
                    starttype)
            return res
```

where `type_` is the first argument to `super()` (the class the method is defined on), `obj` is the instance (so `type(d)` here), and `name` is the attribute you are looking for.