# super() strange behavior in diamond inheritance in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, super, diamond-problem

As the following example shows, `super()` has some strange (at least to me) behavior when used in diamond inheritance.

```
class Vehicle:
    def start(self):
        print("engine has been started")

class LandVehicle(Vehicle):
    def start(self):
        super().start()
        print("tires are safe to use")

class WaterCraft(Vehicle):
    def start(self):
        super().start()
        print("anchor has been pulled up")

class Amphibian(LandVehicle, WaterCraft):
    def start(self):
        # we do not want to call WaterCraft.start, amphibious
        # vehicles don't have anchors
        LandVehicle.start(self)
        print("amphibian is ready for travelling on land")

amphibian = Amphibian()
amphibian.start()
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
engine has been started
anchor has been pulled up
tires are safe to use
amphibian is ready for travelling on land
```

When I call `super().some_method()`, I would never expect a method of a class on the same inheritance level to be called. So in my example, I would not expect `anchor has been pulled up` to appear in the output.

The class calling `super()` may not even know about the other class whose method is eventually called. In my example, `LandVehicle` may not even know about `WaterCraft`.

Is this behavior normal/expected and if so, what is the rationale behind it?

Comment: That behavior is most of the point of Python's `super`. (Yes, the name is confusing.)

Comment: Read this: [super considered super](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)

Comment: So I should never user `super` for calling base class method's? What is it good for then, why is it a good thing that it can also go down the inheritance chain?

Comment: Oddly enough, I can't find a duplicate for this question... but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33469090/1222951) explains the behavior you've observed.

Comment: Because that's the whole point! If you don't want the methods to be called why inherit from the class?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I may want to use other behavior of the class, but inside `start` method, I would just want to use the other base class method, so that's why I call the method belonging to that other class explicitly (`LandVehicle.start(self)`) instead of using `super()`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390553/calling-super-class-method-in-multiple-inheritance) is technically a duplicate, but I like neither the question nor the answer very much. I think we can do better than that.

Comment: If an `Amphibian` doesn't have an anchor, then either it should not inherit from `WaterCraft`, or `WaterCraft` should allow for an *optional* anchor.

Comment: @chepner Let's suppose the implementation of `start` in `Watercraft` is a default implementation on the premise that most watercrafts have anchors, but the ones that don't can override the method. This is exactly what `Amphibian` is trying to accomplish. How is it supposed to know that in some way, its overridden base method will still get called (as a result of calling the same method of another base class) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use inheritance in Python, each class defines a Method Resolution Order (MRO) that is used to decide where to look when a class attribute is looked up. For your `Amphibian` class, for instance, the MRO is `Amphibian`, `LandVehicle`, `WaterCraft`, `Vehicle` and finally `object`. (You can see this for yourself by calling `Amphibian.mro()`.)

The exact details of how the MRO is derived are a little complicated (though you can find a description of how it works if you're interested). The important thing to know is that any child class is always listed before its parent classes, and if multiple inheritance is going on, all the parents of a child class will be in the same relative order they are in the `class` statement (other classes may appear in between the parents, but they'll never be reversed relative to one another).

When you use `super` to call an overridden method, it looks though the MRO like it does for any attribute lookup, but it starts its search further along than usual. Specifically, it starts to search for an attribute just after the "current" class. By "current" I mean, the class containing the method in which the `super` call (even if the object the method is being called on is of some other more derived class). So when `LandVehicle.__init__` calls `super().__init__`, it begins checking for an `__init__` method in the the first class after `LandVehicle` in the MRO, and finds `WaterCraft.__init__`.

This suggests one way you could fix the issue. You could have `Amphibian` name `WaterCraft` as its first base class, and `LandVehicle` second:

```
class Amphibian(Watercraft, LandVehicle):
    ...
```

Changing the order of the bases will also change their order in the MRO. When `Amphibian.__init__` calls `LandVehicle.__init__` directly by name (rather than using `super`), the subsequent `super` calls will skip over `WaterCraft` since the class they're being called from is already further along in the MRO. Thus the rest of the `super` calls will work as you intended.

But that's not really a great solution. When you explicitly name a base class like that, you may find that it breaks things later if you have your more child classes that want to do things differently. For instance, a class derived from the reordered-base `Amphibian` above might end up with other base classes in between `WaterCraft` and `LandVehcle`, which would also have their `__init__` methods skipped accidentally when `Amphibian.__init__` calls `LandVehcle.__init__` directly.

A better solution would be to allow all the `__init__` methods to get called in turn, but to factor out the parts of them you might not want to always run into other methods that can be separately overridden.

For example, you could change `WaterCraft` to:

```
class WaterCraft(Vehicle):
    def start(self):
        super().start()
        self.weigh_anchor()

    def weigh_anchor(self):
        print("anchor has been pulled up")
```

The `Amphibian` class could override the anchor specific behavior (e.g. to do nothing):

```
class Amphibian(LandVehicle, WaterCraft):
    def start(self):
        super().start(self)
        print("amphibian is ready for travelling on land")

    def weigh_anchor(self):
        pass # no anchor to weigh, so do nothing
```

Of course in this specific case, where `WaterCraft` doesn't do anything other than raise its anchor, it would be even simpler to remove `WaterCraft` as a base class for `Amphibian`. But the same idea can often work for non-trivial code.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the detailed answer. I really like the solution that the method should be factored out. My only remaining worry is about cases where you don't have access to the base classes and so can't apply such changes to it. (In that case, the other solution may still work though, but what if it can't be used either...)